# What is the highest possible number of attacks per round for a creature with four arms?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, optimization

What is the highest possible number of melee attacks that one could get consistently in one round for a four-armed creature? Exploiting possible understatements and lacks of limiters in the rules is desired.

When I say “consistently”, I mean a number that could be written down in the stat block. Examples of things that are too inconsistent are Attacks of Opportunity, Robilar's Gambit, Cleave, Greater Cleave, or any other way of getting extra attacks that depend on a triggering event — because they're conditional on something else happening first. The solution should be a fixed number that doesn't depend on hit chances or other statistical outcomes, even if they're statistically consistent in theory. **However if it really is possible to make the triggering event constant, and everworking it may be used.** I just want to build a creature that has “*X* attacks per round”.

The CR shouldn't be greater than 50. If the creature's type is a requirement for a feature, it will not be a problem. Materials from 3.0, Dragon Magazine, Dungeon Adventures and Wizards Archives are acceptable.

Comment: *Fifty?* Is this an actual problem that you're trying to solve? I mean, it's cool if it *is*, but most folks' games don't involve ECL 50 characters. (And why is such a creature limited to a mere *four* arms?)

Comment: [This](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=146.0) is right out, but a lot of [these](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?127463-3-X-Extra-attacks-natural-attacks-AoO&p=7066595#post7066595) are acceptable. Is that correct?

Comment: @HeyICanChan 4 arms only and must be melee :p

Comment: The players will be around 45-48 ECL for that encounter. The concept of the enemy (really plot-dependant) is a forgotten four-armed god.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Infinite. There are multiple ways to achieve that.

For example, a pair of *+1 aptitude kukris*, the Lightning Maces feat, and the Roundhouse Kick feat, on a disciple of Dispater build. Toss in a few rerolls to ensure it starts off properly. This build can threaten a critical on just about any attack that actually hits, and every critical generates two more attacks—which can each critical themselves and generate two more attacks each. Since your number of attacks goes *up* rather than down each time you hit, statistically you are unlikely to ever stop. Having a decent number if initial attacks and some rerolls ensure that you get the ball rolling properly.

Or, ya know, Pun-pun.

Comment: Your answer helped me realise some requirements that I hadn't explained fully in my question. I see that you are quite experienced with D&D. Could you update your answer please? How is it without variables, only with constant features?

Comment: @Momonga-sama It’s still infinite. Your question still makes Pun-pun a valid answer, and Pun-pun can have infinite everything if he wants to. And there are myriad ways to have “as many as you want” even if it is not technically “infinite.”

Comment: Could you add some source to that?